# Is it possible to drag and drop an equation from PowerPoint to edit in LaTeXit without overwriting what is already there?

Tags: mac, powerpoint, latexit

I'm pretty new to LaTeXit, and I'm not sure if this is possible but it would save me so much time. Basically I want to be able to drag an equation I've already added to a PowerPoint (2016 Mac) back into LaTeXit but I want to be able to append to what is already in the editor. The way I format reports means that I have to type up pieces of equations in different places and then combine them into a long equation later in the report. My current solution is just to copy what is in the editor, drag the equation over, and then paste what was already there to append the equation.

Comment: Close voters: I don't think this question is off topic. LaTeXit is a standalone equation editor for the Mac that uses a regular TeX distribution. This is a tool that can be used with Powerpoint, but the question is fundamentally about LaTeXit, which is on topic.